# How to add dollar sign to field without it being included in the value

Tags: javascript, html

I need to add a dollar sign to a box that displays the total amount paying, but I dont want that dollar sign to be included in the "value" tag. Here's what I have now.

```html
<input type="number" class="total" id="totalpaying" name="totalpaying" value="<% total %>" readonly>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Css you can achieve this.

HTML

```
<div class="text">input type="number" class="total" id="totalpaying" name="totalpaying" value="<% total %>" readonly></div>
```

Css

```
<style>
div.text{
position:relative;
padding-left: 20px;
}

div.text:after{
position: absolute;
    left: 6px;
    top: 2px;
    content: '$';
}
</style>
```

Here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/12efgo6t/1/

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a container that is styled like a text box
2. Inside this container add two inline elements:

   - a span to hold the currency symbol
   - an input textbox to hold the value
3. Style the input element to have no borders.

This will create the illusion of a textbox with a currency symbol.  The symbol will not be editable.

Answer (score -1):

As written, the answer to the question is "you can't". If you want the `<input>` element to show "$1.00", the "$" will need to be part of the `value` property.

Now, that being said, there are ways to do what you want, mostly involving using Javascript to manage the value of the input element.

For example, you could add event handlers to manipulate the value when it's in various states.

1. when the input element is initialized with the value "1", add some Javascript to take that "1" and format it as "$1.00"
2. when the user clicks in the input element element (or tabs into it) to start editing, use the `onFocus` handler to strip the "$" sign, so that the user is editing "1.00"
3. when the user clicks somewhere else (or tabs out of the input element), use the `onBlur` handler to reformat the value as "$1.00"

This is a **very** simple example and, depending on your needs, may or may not be what you want. One could certainly write Javascript handlers for the `onFocus`, `onChange`, `onKeyUp/onKeyDown`, and `onBlur` handlers to keep that "$" in there during editing, but that will be much more complicated.